# primeNG V9 table data doesn't persist on screen in angular 9

Tags: angular, primeng

The data being passed takes the form: [ { "field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"....  } ] the data is all at a single level, there is no nesting.

so now to keep it as simple as possible to start, I'm simply trying to output some of the field values (not all).

so I have the following code:

```
<p-table id="tblRequestResponse" [value]="requestResponse" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" sortField="dateTime" sortOrder="-1" #dt>

<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr>
        <th>field1</th>
        <th>field2</th>
        <th>field3</th>
        <th>field4</th>
        <th>field5</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
      <tr>
        <td>{{rowData.field1}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.field2| datexutc:'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.field3}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.field4}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.field5}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>

</p-table>
```

Now the headers stay on the page, but the body data flashes on to the screen but doesn't stay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your code in ts file, i think there is something wrong, look at this link..

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-of3jm8)

hope this will help you, let me know if you still have an issue with this..

thanks

Comment: hi @bilpor let me know if i am doing something wrong or any issue?

Comment: that's interesting. That it what I want. But it's not happening for me. I'll compare what you have done in your code snippet with my code and see if I can see anything different. Will get back to you...and thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Kushal, on the import for DataTable I receive an error stating node_modules/primeng/primeng has no exported member 'DataTable' do I need to install this seperately from the rest? I see you've used primeng 6.3, I'm using 9

Comment: hi you do not need to install it seperately it will come from primeng package just put this line in your ts file `import {  DataTable } from "primeng/primeng";`

Comment: hi @bilpor replace `DataTable` to `any` type because there is no any specification for `DataTable` in documentation of primeNg version 9.

Comment: is there any other error? which you are getting or not working ?

Comment: Hi Kushal, what do I import though, and where you might have `@ViewChild(dataTable) public dataTable: DataTable1` not sure that will work with `any`, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Ok... I've got it :) basically I needed to use primeng/Table. and the reason my data wasn't showing was that from V4 of PrimeNg we had a FilterConstraints on the data which no longer exists, so now I need to figure that one out, but that's another issue.

Comment: okay great let me know if you need any help, I would like to do it ,thanks